# Return the position (row and column) of a data group in a DataFrame [Pandas]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Very good morning to all. I am working with Pandas, I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[90.0,10.0,10.0,20.0,10.0], [30.0,30.0,20.0,70.0,20.0], [30.0,20.0,10.0,20.0,10.0], [20.0,10.0,80.0,10.0,0.0]], index=['v_12','v_23','v_34','v_15'], columns=['C_1','C_2','C_3','C_4','C_5'])

       C_1   C_2   C_3   C_4   C_5
v_12  90.0  10.0  10.0  20.0  10.0
v_23  30.0  30.0  20.0  70.0  20.0
v_34  30.0  20.0  10.0  20.0  10.0
v_15  20.0  10.0  80.0  10.0   0.0
```

***And I'm looking for some method/function in Pandas that allows me to know the position (row and column) of the values that are greater than or equal to 70*** *(I know this can be solved using loops and conditional statements, but I want to preside over them.)*

I would like to get a result similar to this:

```
   Value   Row     Colum
0  90.0    v_12    C_1
1  70.0    v_23    C_4
2  80.0    v_15    C_3
```

I know that using the "where" method, I can get a DataFrame like this:

```
df.where(df>=70)

       C_1  C_2   C_3   C_4  C_5
v_12  90.0  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
v_23   NaN  NaN   NaN  70.0  NaN
v_34   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
v_15   NaN  NaN  80.0   NaN  NaN
```

But the truth is I don't know how to solve this exercise, without making use of a cycle that goes through element by element.

If you know of any function that can help me obtain a similar result, I would greatly appreciate your collaboration. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = 'index', var_name = 'column').query('value>=70')

   index column  value
0   v_12    C_1   90.0
11  v_15    C_3   80.0
13  v_23    C_4   70.0
```

Or

```
df.stack().reset_index(name='value').query('value>=70')

   level_0 level_1  value
0     v_12     C_1   90.0
8     v_23     C_4   70.0
17    v_15     C_3   80.0
```

The above is credited to [@Henry Ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680288/return-the-position-row-and-column-of-a-data-group-in-a-dataframe-pandas/67680367?noredirect=1#comment119628542_67680367)

You could also do:

```
ind = np.where(df>=70)

pd.DataFrame([(val, df.index[row], df.columns[col]) \
              for val, (row, col) in zip(df.values[ind], zip(*ind))])
      0     1    2
0  90.0  v_12  C_1
1  70.0  v_23  C_4
2  80.0  v_15  C_3
```

Comment: Just as a "hey you can do this", when calling reset_index on a series you can pass a name kwarg `df.stack().reset_index(name='value')` instead of `df.stack().reset_index().rename({0:'value'}, axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Extended your approach and bought in the `df.melt`.  Have a great day.

Code

```
df1 = df.where(df>=70).reset_index()
df1 = df1.melt(id_vars='index')
df1 = df1[~df1.value.isna()]
df1.rename(columns={'index':'row','variable':'column'},inplace=True)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)[['value','row','column']]
df1
```

Prints

```
    value   row column
0   90.0    v_12    C_1
1   80.0    v_15    C_3
2   70.0    v_23    C_4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) on results from [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where) and let stack automatically drop the NaNs:

```
new_df = df.where(df >= 70).stack().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'level_0': 'Row', 'level_1': 'Column', 0: 'Value'}
)[['Value',  'Row', 'Column']]
```

```
   Value   Row Column
0   90.0  v_12    C_1
1   70.0  v_23    C_4
2   80.0  v_15    C_3
```

Or [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) then filter for the condition:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[90.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0], [30.0, 30.0, 20.0, 70.0, 20.0],
     [30.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0], [20.0, 10.0, 80.0, 10.0, 0.0]],
    index=['v_12', 'v_23', 'v_34', 'v_15'],
    columns=['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3', 'C_4', 'C_5']
)

stacked = df.stack().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'level_0': 'Row', 'level_1': 'Column', 0: 'Value'}
)

stacked = stacked.loc[
    stacked['Value'].ge(70),  # Filter rows
    ['Value',  'Row', 'Column']  # Re-order columns
].reset_index(drop=True)  # Fix Index

print(stacked)
```

`stacked`:

```
   Value   Row Column
0   90.0  v_12    C_1
1   70.0  v_23    C_4
2   80.0  v_15    C_3
```